# XNA: Position of entities in a list

Tags: xna

I am making a vertical platformer. The way I have been placing the platforms is through lists:

```
      public void LoadPlatforms(ContentManager content, Mechanic_Levels mech, Clide clide)
    {
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());
        platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform());


       // factory.Add(new Entity_Factory());

        foreach (Entity_Platform platform in platforms)
        {
            platform.position = new Vector2(rand.Next(20, 280), rand.Next(20, 580));
            platform.currentlevel = rand.Next(12);
            platform.LoadPlatform(content);
           }
        }
```

This works for if I want randomly placing platforms but how would I set it up so that depending on the current level the platforms reposition themselves individually? I am aware that this will probably mean I can't use lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "reposition themselves"? and what does `currentLevel` do?

Comment: Sorry, should've defined what I meant but current level. So the game works that when you go past the top of the screen the level goes up one. This is handled by a simple integer based system where the if the currentlevel of the platform is equal to the players level then the platform renders. What I mean by re-position is basically instead of having the random system I have now I have a system that sets up a level I designed.

Comment: so instead of the random position in the loop, you should assign the position when adding the platofrm to the list. This can be assigned in code, possibly via a method such as `GetPlatformsForLevel(int level)` or pull the data from an external source (DB, config file, etc.). regarding the currently level you definitely don't want that to be random. Because you will be storing platforms that you don't need or use - though I suppose thats depends on performance, i.e. how fast you levels switch (is there time to load the next set of platforms each time?)

Comment: I'll give that a try, thank you for the help. Sorry about being a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you a 100%, but you can sort your `Entity_Platform`s inside the `List<Entity_Platform>` by supplying a comparison method like

```
private static int ComparePlatforms(Entity_Platform x, Entity_Platform y)
{
        //compare your platforms according to chosen critieria
        //should return 1 if x > y, 0 if x == y, and -1 if x < y
}
```

Afterwards you can use

```
platforms.Sort(ComparePlatforms);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) for an MSDN-example.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps a bit of an answer (rather than the comments) is appropriate. I think what you are asking is how to load a collection of platforms for each level based on a predetermine design.

Keeping your current `LoadPlatforms` method, I would add another method which will get the platforms based on the level. For example:

```
public List<Entity_Platform> GetPlatformsForLevel(int level)
{
    //for this example I will hard-code the platforms, you can pull them from another source if you wish

    List<Entity_Platform> platforms = new List<Entity_Platform>();

    switch(level)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform() { currentLevel = level, position = new Vector2(100, 50) });
            platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform() { currentLevel = level, position = new Vector2(200, 100) });
            platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform() { currentLevel = level, position = new Vector2(300, 75) });
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        {
            platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform() { currentLevel = level, position = new Vector2(80, 20) });
            platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform() { currentLevel = level, position = new Vector2(160, 200) });
            platforms.Add(new Entity_Platform() { currentLevel = level, position = new Vector2(250, 50) });
        }
        break;
    }

    return platforms;
}
```

Then you can call this within your `LoadPlatforms` method like so:

```
public void LoadPlatforms(ContentManager content, Mechanic_Levels mech, Clide clide)
{
    int currentLevel = 1;//you need to track the current level somewhere

    List<Entity_Platform> platforms = GetPlatformsForLevel(currentLevel);

    foreach (Entity_Platform platform in platforms)
    {
        platform.LoadPlatform(content);
    }
}
```